# Need help to click the radio buttons by using Selenium , PYTHON

Tags: python, selenium

```
   <label for="CREDIT" class="_8J-bZE _3C6tOa _2i24Q8">
        <input type="radio" class="_2haq-9" name="paymentOptions" readonly="" id="CREDIT" value="on">
        <div class="_6ATDKp"></div>
         <div class="_2o59RR">
        </div>
        </label>

        <label for="NET_OPTIONS" class="_8J-bZE _3C6tOa _2i24Q8">
        <input type="radio" class="_2haq-9" name="paymentOptions" readonly="" id="NET_OPTIONS" value="on">
        <div class="_6ATDKp"></div>
        <div class="_2o59RR"></div>
        </label>
```

There are the two radio buttons with same class name and I want to click the second one ( NET OPTIONS). I am new to python and selenium both any help will be appriciated. I have tried Xpath and locating ID both but still NO sucess

```
driver.find_element_by_id("NET_OPTIONS").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='container']/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/label[3]").click()
```

after trying the above code , I am getting this error, However radio button is very much visible on the page but , webriver is nit able to locate it :(
**.selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException‌​: Message: element not visible**

Comment: Use `find_element_by_id()`.

Comment: Check if your radio button located inside an `iframe`

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Thanks @Kapil for your reply  .......selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible ....thts the error I am getting , radio button is very much visbible on the screen but somehow , slenium webdriver is unable to find it .

Comment: try this code and lets see if it works- 
`element = driver.find_element_by_id("NET_OPTIONS")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)`

Comment: you are legend!!....I dont know exactly  how ??,but yes it works . Thanks a lot !!!!!! .

Comment: @gauravtyagi - Thanks Man. Glad, it worked. Added it as an answer. Accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code and lets see if it works-

```
 element = driver.find_element_by_id("NET_OPTIONS")
 driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward. Assuming `driver` is your Selenium webdriver, you can click the button you want by simply finding it via it's `id`:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_id("NET_OPTIONS")
button.click()
```